# Insert dates into Microsoft Access database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

How can I write the right syntax to insert a date into my database?

This the SQL command that I already tried:

```
"insert into table1 (date) values (#"+DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())+"#)"
```

And also that:

```
"insert into table1 (date) values ('"+DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())+"')"
```

Comment: Why convert to Date to string if the database already is a date?

Comment: @jdweng because in my database i change the date format to shortdate format

Comment: bat its not the point i need just the syntex to insert the date

Comment: @crank  You say that the other comments are "not the point", but what they recognize is that there is a misunderstanding of what each part of the given code does.  If you understood the finer details of what Parse and ToShortDateString are doing, you would likely understand why the syntax is incorrect.  My answer goes beyond just the syntax and hopefully describes why the other code is incorrect.  I hope that helps you on multiple levels.

Comment: Do you mean small Date?  Still it is a number and not a string with accuracy of 1 minute.

Answer (score 1):

I was certain that I could find a duplicate of this question on Stackoverflow, but it turns out that the many question I found regarding C# and the date format for Access SQL all have their own particular strange issues and no answer was straightforward.  BUT, the answer still technically exists in the other Q&A if you simply look at the format of the strings in various code examples.

- The intention here is to build an SQL **string**.  Both non-working examples are calling the `DateTime.Parse()` method which returns a DateTime value... which is not of String data type.
- The given code is going full circle.  The method `DateTime.Now` returns a DateTime type.  But then the `ToShortDateString()` method converts it to a string.  But then the `Parse()` function will convert that string back into a date, essentially undoing what you already have.

---

Moral of the story?  Remove the call to DataTime.Parse().

```
"insert into table1 (date) values (#" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "#)"
```

Comment: @crank  You didn't share that actual code, so I can't help you there.  The code I shared should produce a valid string.  Perhaps your regional settings are formatting the date as an incompatible string for Access to interpret correctly.  It's up to you to debug each portion of your code and see what it's producing.

Comment: Gustav's code also demonstrates a good point:  You should avoid using reserved words as column names.  `date` is a VBA function, so unless you wrap it like `[date]`, that might also cause errors.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a proper string expression for the date expression, or use Date():

```
"insert into table1 ([date]) values (Date())"
```

For other date values:

```
"insert into table1 ([date]) values (#" + someDate.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#)"
```